# Mondial DB Inner Query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to answer the following question as part of the Mondial DB.

```
-- For each country display the city with the highest population together with the number of the population.
```

The tables are:

Country (**Code**, Name, Capital, Province, Area, Population)

City (**Name**, Country, Province, Longitude, Latitude, Population)

So far, I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    Country.Name, MaxCity.CityName, MaxCity.Population
FROM
    (SELECT 
        MAX(Population) AS Population,
            City.Country,
            City.Name AS CityName
    FROM
        City
    GROUP BY City.Country) AS MaxCity
        JOIN
    Country ON Country.Code = MaxCity.Country;
```

Where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in this way ( I added an extra join)

```
SELECT 
    Country.Name, City.CityName, City.Population
FROM
    Country Join City On Country.Code = City.Country
Join (SELECT 
        MAX(Population) AS Population,Country as Country from City Group By Country)  as X
On City.Country = x.Country and City.Population = x.Population
```

Answer (score 1):

In the origin query need add in group by the field city.name

```
    select country.name, maxcity.cityname, maxcity.population
    from
        (select 
            MAX(population) as population,
        city.country,
        city.name as cityname
    from city
    group by city.country, city.name) as maxcity
            join
    country on country.code = maxcity.country
```